# trigger to Update product dates

Tags: trigger, error

I'm trying to write a trigger to Update product dates when opp close date changes .Below is what i've tried so far,

```
trigger productUpdate on Opportunity (after update) {

    // declare list to hold opportuity line item
    List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

    // declare a set to hold opporrunity ids
    // loop through trigger to get all ids of updated opportuniities
    Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();

    // fetch all line items for the opportnities updated order by opportunitiy id
    olis = [SELECT Id, Name, ServiceDate, Opportunity__r.CloseDate FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :Ids];

    //loop through line items
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : olis ){
        // perform logic to get date
        oli.ServiceDate = oli.Opportunity__r.CloseDate + (10);
    }
    update olis;

}
```

[EDIT]
It gives me error as Didn't understand relationship 'Opportunity__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Please help !

Comment: Five points: (1) you didn't populate the variable `Ids`, (2) you can just use :Trigger.new instead of using a set, (3) you don't need to initialize `olis` on that line, because a query *is* initialization, (4) you don't need to query `ServiceDate` or `Name` or even `Id`, and (5) you should probably use Date.addDays instead of `+(10)`, which has the same meaning but may not be as clear to future developers.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I got with (5) point .Could you please help me to achieve the points you mentioned . Not able to see the updated date on products also after i changed the closed date on opp.

Comment: `trigger updateServiceDate on Opportunity (after update) { OpportunityLineItem[] items = [SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityID IN :Trigger.new]; for(OpportunityLineItem item: items) item.ServiceDate = Trigger.newMap.get(item.OpportunityId).CloseDate.addDays(10); update items; }` is approximately how I'd write it. It should work fine, as I've used code like this in the past.

Comment: There are number of products added to particular opportunity and each one has different ServiceDate . So I want to add the difference (service date - Opportunity.closeDate) to each of them so that every product service date is pushed to a new date with difference equal to the number of days between service date and close date.

Comment: I have tried this:

OpportunityLineItem[] olis = [SELECT Id, Name, ServiceDate, Opportunity.CloseDate FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :Trigger.New];
 for(OpportunityLineItem oli : olis ){
  Integer dat=oli.ServiceDate.day();
  System.debug('dat prod '+ oli + dat);
  Integer dot=oli.Opportunity.CloseDate.day();
  System.debug('opp cd '+ dot);
  Integer diff=dat-dot;
     System.debug('diff'+ diff);
        oli.ServiceDate = Trigger.newMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).CloseDate.addDays(diff);

Comment: @sfdcox The date difference doesnt show up right here . For eg, lets say Prod1 is BMW and Prod2 is Audi. When i chnage opp closedate the prod1 date should add 10 days,Prod2 should add 20 days from closedate.

Comment: That's not what your original code did either. If you're trying to adjust by the original date offset, you'll need to figure the offset for each opportunity and adjust.

Comment: any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

'__r' is appended only in case of custom relationships. These are standard objects so you can simply use

olis = [SELECT Id, Name, ServiceDate, Opportunity.CloseDate FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :Ids];

And

oli.ServiceDate = oli.Opportunity.CloseDate + (10)

Comment: btw, there is no Name field in OpportunityLineItem. You can remove that.